# Zend framework2 + routing with parameter

Tags: php, linker, routes, zend-framework2

I want to write custom routing in Zend framework2. I prepared following code:

```
'objects' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/objects',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'decode',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:mask]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'mask' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-.,]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(

                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

I must routing adres like this:

> http://restaurations.en/objects/**cracow,0.html**
>
> http://restaurations.en/objects/**cracow,swam,1.html**
>
> http:restaurations.en/objects/**swam,3.html**

The blod text I must get in my controller.
Also, How should I prepre corect router??  How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the defaults as well something like this:

```
'objects' => array(
        'type' => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/objects',
            'defaults' => array(
                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                'controller' => 'Index',
                'action' => 'decode',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/[:mask]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'mask' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-.,]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                          '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                          'controller' => 'Index',
                          'action' => 'decode',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Then on your controller to get the param you should do:

```
 $mask = $this->params()->fromRoute('mask');
```

Comment: ok, but I can't use plugings. I have bad preg_match because I receives error like this: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 37 in C:\wamp\www\restauracje\vendor\ZendFramework-2.2.0\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment.php on line 370

Comment: try this                     'route' => '/[:mask].html',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'mask' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-,]+',
                    ),

Comment: sorry my mistake, the text about the plugings was pasted by mistake. :)

Comment: please make an easy test, this url: http://restaurations.en/objects/cracow and this route:                     'route' => '/[:mask]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'mask' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
                    ),

Comment: I solved my problem like this:


My router: 
                            'route' => '[/:mask].html',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                 'mask' => '[a-zA-Z\,\.0-9]+', 
                           
                                
    


Thanks for all:-)

Comment: I am happy you fix your issue